# Javascript! I want to click a button, click a link to vote and reload the page in console

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh, getelementbyid

This is my code in the image below. I need someone to show my errors

Here is my code;

```
var input = document.getElementById('poll-answer-16');

set interval(function(){
button.click() 
}, );

var input = document.getElementById('win');

set interval(function(){
button.click()
}, );
setInterval(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: JavaScript! You have syntax errors, fix those by looking at what they are in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone may correct me if I am wrong but your setInterval does not have any delay parameter.

also you set button.click() so looks like a function but it is not but there is not even listener attached to your input variable so the browser does not know when do executethe function

you should have something more like:

```
var input = document.getElementById(id);
input. addEventListener('click', () => {
     //code to run
});
```

also you have set a variable in the same scope with the same name so the second variable will overwrite the first making it incomplete

I hoped this helped a bit would say more but I am not sure what you want it to do